# Why is my reverse for loop with setInterval() not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a sequence of images which iterates through and changes their opacity to 1, creating an animation effect. I now need to reverse the animation/sequence, however my reverseSequence() function with for loop isn't working and breaks the app.

My code is as follows:

```
forwardSequence() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      (function(idx) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          images[idx].style.opacity = 1;
        }, 50 * (idx + 1))
      })(i);
    }
  }

  reverseSequence() {
    let images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");
    for (var i = images.length; i > 0; i--) {
      (function(idx) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          images[idx].style.opacity = 0;
        }, 50 * (idx + 1))
      })(i);
    }
  }
```

Images:

```
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image1" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image2" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image3" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image4" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image5" /><br>
```

app.scss

```
.imageSequence {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly encourage use of `async` and `await` -

```js
async sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async forwardSequence() {
  let images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");
  for (const img of images) {
    await sleep(50)
    img.style.opacity = 1
  }
}

async reverseSequence() {
  let images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");
  for (let i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    await sleep(50)
    images[i].style.opacity = 0
  }
}
```

Or at the very least, use Promises. It would probably make sense to pass the sequence as an argument to `forward` or `reverse` -

```
const sleep = ms =>
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

forward(sequence) {
  Array.prototype.reduce.call
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) =>
        r.then(_ => sleep(50))
         .then(_ => img.style.opacity = 1)
    , Promise.resolve()
    )
}

reverse(sequence) {
  Array.prototype.reduceRight.call // <-- reduceRight
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) =>
        r.then(_ => sleep(50))
         .then(_ => img.style.opacity = 0)
    , Promise.resolve()
    )
}
```

Further abstraction makes your code even more generic and thus more reusable; win/win! -

```
forward(sequence, effect) { // <-- effect parameter added
  Array.prototype.reduce.call
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) => r.then(_ => sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
    , Promise.resolve()
    )
}

reverse(sequence, effect) { // <-- effect parameter added
  Array.prototype.reduceRight.call
    ( sequence
    , (r, img) => r.then(_ => sleep(50)).then(_ => effect(img))
    , Promise.resolve()
    )
}
```

Using it is like this -

```
const seq =
  document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage")

forwardSequence(seq, img => img.style.opacity = 1)

reverseSequence(seq, img => img.style.opacity = 0)
```

Comment: Zakary, you're welcome. I made a small update which shows how you can make your code more flexible :D

Comment: That's great, I've just seen this so thank you again - one question I do have as I'm still very much learning this stuff - how would I call the forwardSequence on a button and reverseSequence on a different button? Currently I would do the following: 

<button onClick={this.forwardSequence}>Forward Animation</button><button onClick={this.reverseSequence}>Reverse Animation</button>

Answer (score 1):

`reverseSequence()` is an infinite loop.

Change `for (var i = 51; i > 0; i++) {` to `for (var i = 51; i > 0; i--) {`

Cheers!